# error in install a plugin in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am new in Maven and I want to use qt-jambi in maven. I followed this **[tutorial](http://old.qt-jambi.org/users/maven-repository/)** and Maven gave me the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building iycTest
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'net.sf.qtjambi:qtjambi-maven-plugin' does not exist or no val
id version could be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 26 02:25:57 PST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>mypacakage</groupId>
  <artifactId>iycTest</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>iycTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.qtjambi</groupId>
        <artifactId>qtjambi</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2_01</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.sf.qtjambi</groupId>
            <artifactId>qtjambi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>qtjambi</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sourcesDir>src/main/java</sourcesDir>
                <noObsoleteTranslations>true</noObsoleteTranslations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>qtjambi</id>
            <name>qtjambi</name>
            <url>http://qtjambi.sourceforge.net/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>qtjambi</id>
            <name>qtjambi</name>
            <url>http://qtjambi.sourceforge.net/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

How do I solve it? i am using MS Windows xp and Maven 2.0.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you browse to the [README](http://qt-jambi.org/maven2/README.txt%20%20If%20you%20check%20the%20README%20above%20you%27ll%20see%20that%20the%20repository%20is%20actually%20located%20at:%20%20%20http://repository.qt-jambi.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-before-2011/%20README) you'll find a link at the bottom to the [repository](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811002815/http://repository.qt-jambi.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-before-2011/).  Update your pom.xml then rerun maven:

```
$ mvn --update-plugins clean install

$ mvn --version
 Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 00:44:56-0800)
 Maven home: /home/user/apache-maven-3.0.4
 Java version: 1.7.0_09, vendor: Oracle Corporation
 Java home: /home/user/jdk1.7.0_09/jre
 Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: UTF-8
 OS name: "linux", version: "3.5.0-18-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Answer (score 4):

[update based on @Raymond hint to look into README.txt at old repository location]

The repository has moved so you must change the repository URL. Change all the repository urls from

```
http://qtjambi.sourceforge.net/maven2/
```

to

```
http://repository.qt-jambi.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-before-2011/
```

Also check the new home page at http://qt-jambi.org for additional info.  At this new repository 4.6.3_04 is available for the maven plugin. 4.5.2_01, 4.6.2 and 4.6.3 are available qtjambi itself.

Comment: tnx for answer i changed repository URL and my problem is still remain.

Comment: You changed both of them right? repository and pluginRespository? Just checking :)

Comment: Try adding the version to the plugin it may not be being resolved automatically: <version>4.6.3_04</version>

Comment: @alex.p Thanks.  Put your comment about version in an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @alex.p downand 4.6.3_04 download completed but qtjambi4.6.3_04 not installed it want me install manually with mvn install:install-file, so qtjambi version 4.6.3_04 is not in repository.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the version to the plugin it may not be being resolved automatically:

```
<version>4.6.3_04</version>
```

The available versions you can use for the plugin is at the repository url:

http://old.qt-jambi.org/maven2/net/sf/qtjambi/qtjambi-maven-plugin/

At a guess you'd probably need the same plugin version as the version of qtjambi so in this case you'd need to find the appropriate repository.

Comment: Just to comment as the hostname suggests `old.qt-jambi.org` only existed during decommission and change over with hosting and website.  A previous answer has the `http://repository.qt-jambi.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-before-2011/` which is new URL, simply replace the `http://old.qt-jambi.org/maven2/` part with the new URL (or any replace any previous URL that has a /maven2/ part),  We have HTTP redirection and ability to browser with human web-browser in place to hopefully self-document things.